# Is there a better approach for this custom Formtastic input in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, formtastic

I've been using Formtastic for awhile now, and it's great for speeding up implementation of forms.  However, I have a special case where I need some more customization in what's displayed in my form.  Specifically, the field is a file upload form for uploading images, and on the edit form, I want to show a thumbnail of the current version of the image that has been uploaded.

[image: Desired Form Output]

I've got this working, but it required that I use custom HTML markup, which means that any time Formtastic changes the output format, I need to update my matching HTML.  Here's what I've got right now:

```
<%= form.inputs do %>
    <% if form.object.new_record? -%>
        <%= form.input :image, :required => true, :hint => 'Maximum size of 3MB. JPG, GIF, PNG.' %>
    <% else -%>
        <li class="file input required" id="profile_image_input">
            <label class="label" for="profile_image">Image</label>
            <%= image_tag form.object.image.url(:thumb), :class => 'attachment' %>
            <%= form.file_field :image %>
            <p class="inline-hints">Maximum size of 3MB. JPG, GIF, PNG.</p>
        </li>
    <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Ideally, it would be nice to do something more like the following, where `input_html` is assumed to be the generated HTML for the input, hint, etc.:

```
<%= form.inputs do %>
    <%= form.input :image, :required => true, :hint => 'Maximum size of 3MB. JPG, GIF, PNG.' do |input_html| %>
        <%= image_tag form.object.image.url(:thumb), :class => 'attachment' unless form.object.new_record? %>
        <%= input_html %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Does anything like this already exist?  Or is there another similar option that will make my life easier?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I solved this myself of course.  As always happens when I post here. :P

For anyone looking to do something similar, I created a custom input type derived from Formtastic's file input.

```
class AttachmentInput < Formtastic::Inputs::FileInput
  def image_html_options
    {:class => 'attachment'}.merge(options[:image_html] || {})
  end

  def to_html
    input_wrapping do
      label_html <<
      image_html <<
      builder.file_field(method, input_html_options)
    end
  end

protected

  def image_html
    return "".html_safe if builder.object.new_record?

    url = case options[:image]
    when Symbol
      builder.object.send(options[:image])
    when Proc
      options[:image].call(builder.object)
    else
      options[:image].to_s
    end

    builder.template.image_tag(url, image_html_options).html_safe
  end
end
```

Now I can just create an input of this type in the following manner:

```
<%= form.input :image, :as => :attachment,
                       :required => true,
                       :hint => 'Maximum size of 3MB. JPG, GIF, PNG.',
                       :image => proc { |o| o.image.url(:thumb) } %>
```

Optionally, the `:image` tag can accept one of:

- a Proc, which passes the form's object param,
- a Symbol, which is a method name on the object,
- anything else, which is converted to a string and assumed to represent the URL.

Additionally, I can utilize the `:image_html` option for specifying HTML classes, id's, etc.

Comment: Yup, looks good. I have lots of custom inputs that do stuff like this, or display the value as a String in a disabled input.

Comment: I'm new to editing/adding to source code. Where did you put the AttachmentInput class? Did you put a class in your rails lib folder? Did you put it in the inputs folder? If in the inputs folder how do you manage the different versions? What would happen if Justin updated the code base?

Comment: @ebbflowgo, I pasted the above code into `app/inputs/attachment_input.rb` and it works.

Comment: I want to make the thumbnail image also a link to the full-size image, How do I do that?

Comment: Here's how: wrap it in a `builder.template.link_to( ... )`

Answer (score 7):

At the bottom of the Formtastic docs at https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs:

```
Create a file in app/inputs with a filename ending in _input.rb
```

Not enough for a full solution, but after rooting through the formtastic source for inspiration was able to come up with the following which is working well for me.

in app/inputs/label_input.rb:

```
class LabelInput
  include Formtastic::Inputs::Base

    def to_html
        input_wrapping do
            label_html <<
            "#{@object.send(method)}"
        end
    end
  end
```

happen to be using ActiveAdmin, in form on page:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :project
    f.input :date_consumed
    f.input :total_consumed
    f.input :computed_waste, :as => :label
    f.actions
  end
end
```